# Automatically test if shiny crashes and retrieve error?

Tags: r, exception, shiny

I have an app like this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
        textOutput("Query_String")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(session$clientData$url_search,{
        Query <- session$clientData$url_search
        output$Query_String <- renderText(Query)
        # Long list of operations dependant on the parameters passed in the URL
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

That takes an URL query as parameter.
I have a list with around ~5000 entries for all possible queries that should be accepted by the app
and I can run the app iterating through the queries by calling the app via something like this:

```
runApp(
  appDir = "R",
  port = 3838,
  launch.browser = function(appUrl) {
    url <- paste0(appUrl, "/?query")
    invisible(.Call("rs_shinyviewer", url, getwd(), "browser", NULL, PACKAGE = "(embedding)"))
  },
  host = "0.0.0.0"
)
```

Now my question:

**How can I catch which queries may make the app crash?** 
I have tried wrapping the logic inside the server with a big `tryCatch()` but that apparently doesnt do anything, neither does wrapping the `runApp()` with `tryCatch()` (although this makes sense to me). 
 Ideas?

Comment: A crash is not the same as an exception.  `tryCatch()` catches exceptions.  If the app has crashed, it can't run any more code.  I think you need to identify the condition(s) that case the crash(es) and prevent the failure before it happens.

Comment: Thanks for the insight on why the ```tryCatch()``` approach does not work, makes a lot of sense! I could obviously wrap bits that might lead to a crash inside of the app with ```tryCatch()``` to do what you suggest, however I would like to know if the approach above is viable at all for a rough first check to identify corner-cases of queries that interact with the app in an unexpected way.

Comment: At the end of each query, print a diagnostic.  Something like "Finished with query XXXX".  If you know the order in which the queries run, that will tell you the (first) query that causes the crash.  Implement a fix.  Repeat until satisfied.  The `logger` package (or similar) may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test if shiny app crashes on launch

```
testthat::test_that("server launches",{
local_edition(3)
skip_on_cran()
skip_on_travis()
skip_on_appveyor() 
app <- shinytest::ShinyDriver$new(here::here()) #open shiny app

a <- data.frame(app$getDebugLog()) #check debug log for error

a <- a %>%  
  filter(!grepl('Warning: ', message)) %>% filter(level == "ERROR") 

if (length(grep("Error in", a)) == 0) 
  alive = TRUE
 else 
  alive = FALSE 
expect_true(alive) })
```